# Al hacer push a un hook, solo funciona cuando doy click la segunda vez

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, expo

Estoy tratando de hacer push en un hook, pero por alguna razón solo funciona al dar un segundo click.

```
const [cart, setCart] = React.useState([]);

async function addItemToCart(itemImage,
    itemName,
    itemPrice,
    itemId) {

    let shoppingCart = {
        itemImage: itemImage,
        itemName: itemName,
        itemCuantity: 1,
        itemPrice: itemPrice
    };
```

De esta manera solo funciona al dar un segundo click.

```
setCart([...cart, shoppingCart])
```

Esta es la única solución pero no sé si es correcto.

```
cart.push(shoppingCart)
```

Este es el botón que ejecuta esa función:

```
}

return (
    <Container >
        <Button block style={styles.btnColor} onPress={() => addItemToCart(item.itemImage, item.itemName, item.itemPrice)}>
            <Text>COMPRAR</Text>
        </Button>
    </Container>
);
```

Comment: Agrega el código completo de `addItemToCart`, saludos

Comment: Esta completo..

Comment: Me parece que solo estas compartiendo el componente del botón `addItemToCart`, debería haber componente donde se ve el `cart`, ¿o todo esta en un solo componente?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dado que al parecer no hay suficiente contexto, comento que he visto ese problema cuando tienes focus en un input y luego al hacer click en un botón debo hacerlo por segunda vez para que tome efecto. Esto me pasaba cuando usaba un contenedor que tenía un ScollView y lo solucioné con lo siguiente.

```
<ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps='handled'> ... </ScrollView>
```

Si estas en el mismo caso pero no quisiste compartir todo tu código, puede que te ayude.